# jquery expand <li> right and collapse left

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation

Trying to get a menu `li` item to expand right, showing a search form on a `click` event then close again when anything outside of the search form itself is clicked. I've managed to get the expand to work but can't figure out the collapse. I know there's quite a few questions about this already but I think I'm just too tired to make sense of it... any help appreciated.

**UDPATE:**

Managed to get the effect with a `mouseleave()` event: http://jsfiddle.net/C3YCP/31/

But still out of curiosity, I can't get it to collapse with a click event of some kind?

HTML:

```
<li id="search">
    <a href="#" title="Search" id="searchA">Search</a>
    <div id="searchWrap">
        <form> 
            <fieldset> 
                <input type="text">  
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$("#search").click (function() {
    $(this).animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");
    $("#searchA").animate({width:'180px'},200)','color':'#4d4d4d'});
    $('#searchWrap').show("slide", 200);
    $("#search input").css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    });
$("#searchWrap").click(function() { 
return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
#search { width: 112px; }
#searchA { color: #fff; padding: 18px 35px 53px 9px; } 
#searchWrap { position: absolute; top: 53px; left: 10px; display: none; }
#search form { padding: 0 10px 0 0; }
#search fieldset { border: none; }
#search input { width: 200px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #fff; background-color:#4D4D4D; outline: none; color: #4D4D4D; padding: 0 0 0 3px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");
    $("#searchA").animate({width:'180px'},200).css({'background-image':'url(images/nav-searchgrey.png)','color':'#4d4d4d'});
    $('#searchWrap').show("slide", 200);
    $("#search input").css({'background-color':'#fff','border-color':'#BBBDBF'});

    $('body :not(#searchWrap)').one(function() {
      // Hide search.
    });
});
```

Comment: Whoa there, this can only run once--why use `one()`?

Comment: Because the `.one()` is attached every time the `#search` is clicked and doesn't fire unnecessarily.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense...nice!

Comment: The problem is probably your jQuery version. You're using `1.4`. jQuery `1.7.1` came out a few weeks ago.

Comment: Tried that and still no go? Would you mind checking out this fiddle?   

http://jsfiddle.net/C3YCP/27/

Answer (score 0):

'blur' is an event that is dispatched when the user 'unfocus' the field that is currently focused. You can directly listen to that event by using the blur method in jQuery as such :

```
$('#searchWarp input:first').blur(function(event) {
    // reverse the actions that you made on the 'mouseup' event handler
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML click to detect click outside of the search

```
$('html').click(function() {
   //Change the CSS here to hide
});
```

And don't forgot to include **event.stopPropagation();**

In your case

```
$("#search").mouseup(function(event) {
    $(this).animate({width:'225px'},200).css("background-color","#e5e6e7");
    $("#searchA").animate({width:'180px'},200).css({'background-image':'url(images/nav-searchgrey.png)','color':'#4d4d4d'});
    $('#searchWrap').show("slide", 200);
    $("#search input").css({'background-color':'#fff','border-color':'#BBBDBF'});
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: Attaching the click to the entire `html` tag includes the search itself.

Comment: Yah that's why we have to use event.stoppropogation(), So in search it will ignore the HTML click event.

Comment: But then it will fire `stopPropagation()` when you click the search itself. Also, you forgot to add the `event` parameter to the search mouseup fucntion--otherwise, `event.stopPropagation()` won't work.